# How to get the windows username with Django web page

Tags: django, windows, authentication, web

How can I get the Windows username of the person running my Django web page?

I don't know if and how it matters, but I should note that my site is internal to my company but it's not under my company's domain. Do they need to be on the same domain for security reasons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this module, https://pypi.org/project/django-windowsauth/

It allow you to synchronize the Django User with the Windows User of the visitor for you page.

And about the multiple domain, it doesn't matter that your site is hosted on a different domain from the Active Directory domain.

Comment: Hi @dan, can your module provide me with the Windows user name of the person opening the webpage? So far I am able to get only the IP of the client's Windows desktop, which I check against the AD at my company.

Comment: Definitely, after installing correctly you can use just use {{ user }} in your templates to show the currently connected user's username.
You can even access {{ user.get_full_name }} for or {{ user.ldap }} for the user's full logon name